# Cannot check checkbox - Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, checkbox, thymeleaf

I have a list of users in a table with a column at the end that has checkboxes so if a user clicks on any of the checkboxes, he can delete the user in that row.

However, after I added the `th:field="*{checkedUsers}"` tag, I am not able to click any of the check boxes.

Here is the HTML code for that:

http://pastebin.com/tT9QmVwB

Any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I realize it could be something to do with the `<label>` tag:

> The  tag defines a label for an `<input>` element.
>
> The `<label>` element does not render as anything special for the user.
>   However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because
>   if the user clicks on the text within the `<label>` element, it toggles
>   the control.
>
> The for attribute of the `<label>` tag should be equal to the id
>   attribute of the related element to bind them together.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Is this the problem? And if so, how could I work around it?

**EDIT 2:**

`<label>` had nothing to do with it. I replaced it with `<span>` and I still can't click on any of the check boxes.

**EDIT 3:**

The `th:field="*{checkedUsers}"` field is an ArrayList of `User` objects that are checked and would populate the form-backing bean `DeleteUsersForm`

Here is that bean class:

```
public class DeleteUsersForm {

    private List<User> checkedUsers;

    public DeleteUsersForm() {

    }

    public DeleteUsersForm(List<User> checkedUsers) {
        this.checkedUsers = checkedUsers;
    }

    public void setCheckedUsers(List<User> checkedUsers) {
        this.checkedUsers = checkedUsers;
    }

    public List<User> getCheckedUsers() {
        return checkedUsers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any information on what the checkedUsers field actually is?

Comment: please check edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized it was the CSS that was preventing it this whole time. I am using topcoat.